# How to set limit to back action in fragment

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, kotlin

I have 3 different fragments. It's strange question, but I want to limit transaction to some fragments. For example: if I click back in third fragment, I'll get back to first. And if I click back in first one, it'll back to MainActivity. But all three fragments are shows from another Activity, which called SearchActivity. There is 2 problems getting from this way.
First: My status bar looks a little bit... Just watch on it:
[look at this status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br9xW.png)

My second problem: When I'm going back in fragment (From MainActivity starting SearchActivity with Bottom Navigation Bar with currentItem(0), then I'm pressing back button and, I think it's going to SearchActivity, but I need to go back into MainActivity. Well, to get back into MainActivity, I need to press back twice, because on the first press it's going to SearchActivity) this happens:
[imgur gif](https://i.imgur.com/LU6pnpE.gifv)

My activity:

```
lateinit var toolbar: ActionBar

private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
}

private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.navigation_1 -> {
            toolbar.title = resources.getString(R.string.title_1)
            val firstFragment = FirstView.newInstance()
            openFragment(firstFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_2-> {
            toolbar.title = resources.getString(R.string.title_2)
            val secFragment = SecView.newInstance()
            openFragment(secFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_3 -> {
            toolbar.title = resources.getString(R.string.title_3)
            val thirdFragment = ThirdView.newInstance()
            openFragment(thirdFragment)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)

    toolbar = supportActionBar!!

    val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation)
    bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    bottomNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_1
}
```

And there is activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="s.com.s.SearchActivity">

<!--<FrameLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>-->

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:itemBackground="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Fragment Example:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

    val rv = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.firstView)
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
    val firsts = ArrayList<Hotel>()
    firsts.add(Hotel("Paul", "Mr", R.drawable.abc_list_longpressed_holo))
    firsts.add(Hotel("Jane", "Miss", R.drawable.abc_ratingbar_material))
    firsts.add(Hotel("John", "Dr", R.drawable.abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000))
    firsts.add(Hotel("Amy", "Mrs", R.drawable.abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha))

    var adapter = CustomAdapter(firsts)
    rv.adapter = adapter

    return view
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): FirstView = FirstView()
}
```

And xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/firstView"/>
```

Glad for help, I can't solve it for a week. I hope that I have explained everything well, because I do not even know how to explain it.

Comment: You need to keep track of the current fragment and override onBackPressed. Then you will add some logic in onBackPressed on the activity to determine what to do based on which fragment you are on.

Comment: Do you have any example? I just don't understand how to do it with fragments (Heard only about activities), so... Hope you can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have a possible solution:**

You should need to implement

```
onBackPressed()
```

*(is supported Since: API Level 5)*

And code something like this:

```
  Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  startActivity(i);
```

This will clear all activities data and go back to the main.
Hope it can help you.

Comment: I'll try it later, thanks. But, sorry, I'm not so smart in this. How to solve that problem, when I need to switch fragment to another fragment (for ex. from fr3 to fr1 and nowhere else)? And if you know how to solve first problem - my pleasure to you. Anyway, I'll keep in mind

Comment: Don't worry, first of all.. 
1. You want a status bar? (i don't know if u want but u can delete it)
2. " I want to limit transaction to some fragments. For example: if I click back in third fragment, I'll get back to first. And if I click back in first one, it'll back to MainActivity."  If you want to skipe the "search activity" and go directy to main you need to use the function "onBackPressed" and specify that "when u press back button of u mobile" you will clear the fragments and start the main activity.  I understood that this is what you want.  For more questions reply :)

Comment: thank you very much for such an informative answer. It helped me. I didn't even thought if it's so easy to solve.